# Visual Basic code to detect pendrive

Tags: vb.net

I have this vb code which detects when a pendrive is inserted. Can anyone help me to be able to access the content of the pendrive in my form?? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IO.Directory.GetDirectories()` and `IO.Directory.GetFiles()` from the path of the pendrive. You can see the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), respectively.

Improve your question in order to have more specific answers.

**EDIT:**

Adding the file names into a ListBox:

```
Dim allFiles() As String = Directory.GetFiles(penDrivePath)

For Each file As String in allFiles
    ListBox1.Items.Add(file)
Next
```

Comment: thanks. I would like the files on the pendrive to be shown in a list box